# Parse CSV file with headers when the headers are part way down the page

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file that, as a spreadsheet, looks like this:
[image]

I want to parse the spreadsheet with the headers at row 19. Those headers wont always start at row 19, so my question is, is there a simple way to parse this spreadsheet, and specify which row holds the headers, say by using the "Date" string to identify the header row?

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
CSV.foreach(params['logbook'].tempfile, headers: true) do |row|
  Flight.create(row.to_hash)
end
```

but obviously that wont work because it doesn't get the right headers.

I feel like there should be a simple solution to this since it's pretty common to have CSV files in this format.

Comment: Is everything after the header row you are looking for part of the data you wish to retrieve?

Comment: Yes. The only part I was to ignore is the part above the header row.

Comment: Skip the lines until you have a `YYYY-MM-DD` format date in the first column.

Comment: *since it's pretty common to have CSV files in this format.* I don't think so.

Comment: @arel if is this is exported from a spreadsheet, then just make two sheets and put the bottom part into the second sheet - once you export that second sheet, the CSV will be just perfectly starting with the header line. 
It's just a small change in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `smarter_csv` gem for this. Parse the file once to determine how many rows you need to skip to get to the header row you want, and then use the `skip_lines` option:

```
header_offset = <code to determine number of lines above the header>

SmarterCSV.process(params['logbook'].tempfile, skip_lines: header_offset)
```

Comment: The OP's question is: "How can I write `code to determine number of lines above the header`"?

Comment: Turns out that after all these years that this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first create the csv file that would be produced from the spreadsheet.

```
csv =<<-_
N211E,C172,2004,Cessna,172R,airplane,airplane
C-GPGT,C172,1976,Cessna,172M,airplane,airplane
N17AV,P28A,1983,Piper,PA-28-181,airplane,airplane
N4508X,P28A,1975,Piper,PA-28-181,airplane,airplane
,,,,,,
Flights Table,,,,,,

Date,AircraftID,From,To,Route,TimeOut,TimeIn
2017-07-27,N17AV,KHPN,KHPN,KHPN KHPN,17:26,18:08
2017-07-27,N17AV,KHSE,KFFA,,16:29,17:25
2017-07-27,N17AV,W41,KHPN,,21:45,23:53
_

FName = 'test.csv'
File1.write(FName, csv)
  #=> 395
```

We only want the part of the string that begins `"Date,"`.The easiest option is probably to first extract the relevant text. If the file is not humongous, we can slurp it into a string and then remove the unwanted bit.

```
str = File.read(FName).gsub(/\A.+?(?=^Date,)/m, '')
  #=> "Date,AircraftID,From,To,Route,TimeOut,TimeIn\n2017-07-27,N17AV, 
  #    KHPN,KHPN,KHPN KHPN,17:26,18:08\n2017-07-27,N17AV,KHSE,KFFA,,16:29,
  #    17:25\n2017-07-27,N17AV,W41,KHPN,,21:45,23:53\n"
```

The regular expression that is `gsub`'s first argument could be written in free-spacing mode, which makes it self-documenting:

```
/
\A         # match the beginning of the string
.+?        # match any number of characters, lazily
(?=^Date,) # match "Date," at the beginning of a line in a positive lookahead
/mx        # multi-line and free-spacing regex definition modes
```

Now that we have the part of the file we want in the string `str`, we can use [CSV::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) to create the `CSV::Table` object:

```
csv_tbl = CSV.parse(str, headers: true)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:4>
```

The option `:headers => true` is documented in [CSV::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new).

Here are a couple of examples of how `csv_tbl` can be used.

```
csv_tbl.each { |row| p row }
  #=> #<CSV::Row "Date":"2017-07-27" "AircraftID":"N17AV" "From":"KHPN"\
  #     "To":"KHPN" "Route":"KHPN KHPN" "TimeOut":"17:26" "TimeIn":"18:08">
  #   #<CSV::Row "Date":"2017-07-27" "AircraftID":"N17AV" "From":"KHSE"\
  #     "To":"KFFA" "Route":nil "TimeOut":"16:29" "TimeIn":"17:25">
  #   #<CSV::Row "Date":"2017-07-27" "AircraftID":"N17AV" "From":"W41"\
  #     "To":"KHPN" "Route":nil "TimeOut":"21:45" "TimeIn":"23:53">
```

(I've used the character `'\'` to signify that the string continues on the following line, so that readers would not have to scroll horizontally to read the lines.)

```
csv_tbl.each { |row| p row["From"] }
  # "KHPN"
  # "KHSE"
  # "W41"
```

Readers who want to know more about how Ruby's CSV class is used may wish to read Darko Gjorgjievski's piece, "A Guide to the Ruby CSV Library, [Part 1](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part/) and [Part 2](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part-2/)".

Comment: Fantastic and elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Arel, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From this format, I think the easiest way is to detect an empty line that comes before the header line. That would also work under changes to the header text. In terms of CSV, that would mean a whole line that has only empty cell items.

Comment: Great idea. I can also look for "Flights Table" What I haven't been able to figure out is if there is a simple way to build the headers based on this information, or if I have to manually construct the headers after parsing the CSV. I'm assuming I'll have to do it manually.